# Verify yaml file base an template file

Tags: algorithm, yaml

I want to use a yaml file as a template file with below contents

```
---
cars:
  optional: false
  children:
  - benz:
    optional: false
    children:
    - benz_c:
      optional: true
      children:
      - c180:
        optional: false
        children:
        -
    - benz_a:
      optional: false
      children:
      - a180:
        optional: false
        children:
        -
  - audi:
    optional: true
    children:
    - audi_a:
      optional: true
      children:
      -
```

to varify any yaml files that can meet below conditions

1. if the key is not optional, the key must exist in the same level in the target file
2. if the key is optional, the key can exist or not in the same level in the target file
3. if the parent of the key is optional but exist in target file then the following keys should follow 1 and 2

Below example is valued:

```
---
cars:
  benz:
  - benz_c:
    - c180
  - benz_a:
    - a180
```

Below example are not valued:
benz_c is optional but c180 is not

```
---
cars:
  benz:
  - benz_c
  - benz_a:
    - a180
```

bmw is not a valued option

```
cars:
  benz:
  - benz_c:
    - c180
  - benz_a:
    - a180
  - bmw
```

Comment: You should probably use JSON schema as your template, and then you can use an off-the-shelf package like `ajv` to validate: https://json-schema.org/